# How to copy a .ui file in my qwidgets project?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I wish to try this qt example. I created a qwidgets project, copied all headers and sources from the following example to my project.

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qtmultimedia-audiorecorder-example.html

What is the way to copy the .ui file of that project to my project?

What should be the extention of that file in my project?

Comment: I can't understand what's the trick of your question. In you example the file has `.ui` extension, as well as any GUI file created by Qt Creator. Just copy XML content from example into `*.ui` file and add it to your project. Also there is `audiorecorder.pro` file in the example which shows how to add the ui file.

Comment: @Sergey copying as it is is not possible in Qt creator. That file is not editable.

Comment: Then you may either edit it outside Qt Creator or create `audiorecorder.ui` file with appropriate XML from any other editor and then right-click on project in project explorer -> add existing files... -> select the file you need. Moreover, Qt Creator does not support (or at least did not until recent versions) all Qt widgets, and there is no other way to go if you use `QSplitter` or any other unsupported widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*.ui` files are GUI designer files and define the actual GUI.

Copy it *as-is*. You'll need to invoke the [`uic` (*User Interface Compiler*)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/uic.html) on it to produce the `ui_audiorecorder.h` header file, which is included in the [`audiorecorder.cpp` file](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qtmultimedia-audiorecorder-audiorecorder-cpp.html).

Read more on the *uic* toolchain in the docs: [Using a Designer UI File in Your Application](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html).

Comment: thanks, can the `qtcreator` not automatically generate the `ui_audiorecorder.h` file?

Comment: that doc says "If you use qmake, uic will be invoked automatically for header files.". Does this mean that I just have to copy that ui file outside qtcreator and then run qmake with qtcreator?

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius Why should QtCreator do the same task as the ui compiler is designed to do? Exactly, just copy all files (cpp, h and ui) with the file manager of your choice. It's up to you how you invoke qmake - from the command line or from within QtCreator. The build process (and the way the ui compiler is invoked) is the same.

Comment: sorry, I meant will qtcreator automatically invoke uic? I wrote it wrongly. Thanks for your attention though.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius , yes `uic` will be automatically invoked when running qmake (either from Qt Creator or manually).

Comment: What has uic got to do with anything? You don't invoke it manually. This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You copy the `.ui` file into your project's folder using your favorite file manager or terminal or what have you. Suppose that the file is named `foo.ui`.

Then you add the file to the project by either:

1. Adding the following line to the `.pro` file:

   ```
   FORMS += foo.ui
   ```
2. Right-clicking the root project node, selecting "Add Existing Files...", and navigating to the `foo.ui` file in the file dialog.

The two procedures are equivalent, the result is the same: a new `FORMS` item in the project file.

That's all. As soon as you save the `.pro` file, Qt Creator will parse it and show the `foo.ui` under a `Forms` project tree node.